# What approach do you follow when using animations with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, animation, styled-components

Im trying to create an acordion with react and styled-components.

Im trying changing display: none to display:block and adding a transition, but it changes with no transition, it only works fine if i remove the display property on the styled-component but i can see part of the div if i remove that property.Sorry for my english and thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/z2nj50z46p?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem was in this part of the css

```
const AcordionItemWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;  // This is now 100% and not 80%
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
`;
```

And this change produces this result.

This ensures that your `darkgoldenrod` tab is 100% of it's containers width. When it is active the dropdown is also 100%.

After further investigation I have found your problem. Some mark up issues, plus browser applies a default margin on certain html elements. In this case paragraph has a default margin being applied. background color is ignored when margin is used.

The below link should be what you want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nkj7mx73jj

Comment: its ok, but i cant see the transition its like its not transitioning at all, dont know if i have to play with intervalts or something like that.

Comment: Could you please explain/describe further what animation should be performed?

Comment: Ive a transition on AcordionItemPanel, but it does not do the amimation, it just appear and dissapear.

Comment: Are we talking about the method `changeAcordionState`? As from what I can see from link posted is how i'd expect an accordion tab to behave. Can you describe what the animation should do?

Comment: yes im trying to reproduce this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

Comment: it doesnt work smoothly, if u change the time in transition property it doesnt affect

Comment: I have updated the link, please let me know if that is what you desire?